# Chrome Debugger crashes app on remote device

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, debugging

I have a Cordova app (running latest Cordova) that I'm attempting to diagnose due to its poor performance (it's kinda laggy). Android Emulator's performance is attrocious and Ripple emulator is messing with the results, I'm attempting to test it directly on a device (Mi Pad 2).

Since it's a VS 2015 project, I compile debug version to device and disconnect the debugger (or just run the installed debug version on the device). I then open Chrome's `chrome://inspect/#devices` and connect to the device. No problems so far.

In the **Performance** tab, when I click Record or reload the page, it starts Profilling and then the app on the device crashes after ~5 seconds.

In the **Memory** tab, when I click *Take Heap Snapshot*, it counts to 100% and then starts *Loading...* and hangs there (debugger and app are still responsive, it just never displays any result). The other functions on this tab seem to be working. I dunno whether the Heap Snapshot is even useful, but since it didn't work I though I would mention it.

Any ideas how to get it working? What might be causing it?

Comment: is it showing "Unfortunately closes the app" like this?

Comment: @rajpeer No, as the app crashes the Debugger looses connection to it, so it just says "Debugging connection was closed. Reason: Connection lost" and offers to reconnect (which btw doesn't work).

Comment: On click of performance and memory tab you are doing something right.. comment  inside code, and keep one console.log('some message"'). then see what happen?. if crashes again, there may be something problem

Comment: @rajpeer Ok, so I tried that and it works when I basically comment out the initiating function (only index.html loads and loads it's content along with all the JS and CSS attached to it, but nothing executes).

Comment: @rajpeer Further investigatin points to `AppVar.nav.resetToPage('login.html');` killing the app. It's a OnsenUI's function do reset view to page (basically populates <body> with content). Still, that doesn't help me much in solving my problem. I guess I will try asking on OnsenUI's GitHub.